# JavaScript: xmlhttprequest request and server answer

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm starting off with js.
I want to fetch data from a server with xml. I wonder how to send a request as, and get an anser in xml through javascript functions.
It says I need a POST-Request and send an xml in the form:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ft> 
    <request clientId="123" apiName="api_search_location_stops_nearby" apiVersion="2.0"> 
        <client clientId="123"/> 
        <requestType>api_search_location_stops_nearby</requestType> 
        <outputCoords>WGS84</outputCoords> 
        <fromCoordName>WGS84</fromCoordName> 
        <fromType>coords</fromType> 
        <fromWgs84Lat>48.22</fromWgs84Lat> 
        <fromWgs84Lon>16.39</fromWgs84Lon> 
    </request> 
</ft>
```

To then get an xml answer. It has 2 or 3 nodes in it, which I'm interested in. From there on, it'll be no big deal.

It is all about a strange API from the vienna public transport company:
http://akirk.github.io/Wiener-Linien-API/
I basically want to get (open)data from them.

Here:
https://techscreen.tuwien.ac.at/node/794
I found a solution for php..

My try:

```
 // Bare bones XML writer - no attributes
function xmlElement(name,content){
    var xml
    if (!content){
        xml = '<' + name + '>' + '</' + name + '>'
    }
    else {
        xml = '<'+ name + '>' + content + '</' + name + '>'
    }
    return xml
}



function sendRequest()
{
    var xmlReq
    xmlReq = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    xmlReq = xmlReq + "<ft>";
    xmlReq = xmlReq + "<request clientId=\"123\" apiName=\"api_get_monitor\" apiVersion=\"2.0\">";
    xmlReq = xmlReq +      "<client clientId=\"123\"/>";
    xmlReq = xmlReq + xmlElement("requestType", "api_get_monitor");
    xmlReq = xmlReq + xmlElement("monitor",
                                 xmlElement("outputCoords", "WGS84") +
                                 xmlElement("type","stop") +
                                 xmlElement("name","60201040") +
                                 xmlElement("year","2013") +
                                 xmlElement("month","10") +
                                 xmlElement("day","3") +
                                 xmlElement("hour","8") +
                                 xmlElement("minute","0") +
                                 xmlElement("line") +
                                 xmlElement("sourceFrom","stoplist") );
    xmlReq = xmlReq + "</request>" + "</ft>";

    text1.text = xmlReq;


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = handleRequest;
    xhr.open("POST", "http://webservice.qando.at/2.0/webservice.ft"); // POST or GET
    xhr.send(xmlReq);
    // xhr.responseXML // this is allways null

}


function handleRequest(answer)
{
    console.log(answer.responseType);
    console.log(answer.responseXML);
}
```

The core points of my question: On my code, should there be GET or POST? Is the request built up to fit the style above (or do I need linebreaks or convert to a DOM xml thing)? How does the recieving thing work. Am I doing this right? Should the variable answer then contain the xml with the answer?

This code is somehow not working. I printed the xml-string to the console and it looks just like above (without linebreaks). But the handleRequest function doesn't print anything (it is not called at all).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) If it says you should use POST, then use POST. 2) Yes. You cannot get a response before requesting it. 3) Build the XML by concatenating strings. 4) Then send the XML string in that `postData` variable.

Comment: <<< _2) Yes. You cannot get a response before requesting it._ **+1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was good allready.
I got the wrong clientID. That was basically it. Then there was just a small modification to make:

`xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ page.handleRequest(xhr); }`

..to send the xmlHttpRequest over to the function. This worked for me.